# Prove $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{n^{\ln(n)}}{\ln(n)^n}$ converges or diverges

Tags: real-analysis

My intuition is that this series converges since the denominator grows much faster.
But I'm having trouble proving it. Thanks.

Comment: The sum is infnity if you start with n=1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

We can refer to root test

$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{n^{\log n}}{\log^nn }}=\frac{n^{\frac{\log n}n}}{\log n}=\frac{e^{{\frac{\log^2 n}n}}}{\log n} \to 0$$

then recall that $\frac{\log n}n\to 0$.

Comment: I think I get it now. So just to make sure tho, this limit goes to 0 because to the top expression tends to 1 and the bottom goes to infinity, right?

Comment: @davidh Exactly!

Comment: @user Why  is $ n^{\log(n)} = e^{\log^2(n)}$?

Comment: @Dimitris We have  that $n=e^{\log n}$.

Comment: oh haha my bad, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just apply root test: $\lim a_n^{1/n} =0$.

Comment: @Arthur Sorry. So silly! What I wrote was different from what I was thinking. Thanks.